# Definite Integral from or to; plus or minus infinity

Tags: integration, exponentiation, infinity

I always knew integrating in a common way:

$\int_{n}^{z}{x^y} \ dx=[\frac{z^{y+1}}{y+1}] - [\frac{n^{y+1}}{y+1}]$

All we do is integrate $x^y$ and then replace the $x$ with $z$ first, then subtract it with itself but instead of replacing $z$, we replace $n$. But then I have seen that:

$e^z = \int_{-\infty}^{z}{e^x} \ dx ≠ [e^z] - [e^{-\infty}]$

Because $e^{-\infty}$ is undefined.

Question is, do we use limits for the second term? Unless, then how do we calculate such an integral?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: If you want to be rigorous then yes you would use limits. We can define $e^{-\infty} = \lim_{x \to -\infty} e^x = 0$.

Comment: Note that we should have $0\notin (n,z)$

Answer (score 1):

An integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^b f(x)dx
$$
is understood as
$$
\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_{a}^b f(x)dx,
$$
if such limit exists.